# Custom styleable for android 4.4 not available

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles, declare-styleable

So i have a probleme with custom styleable in android 4.4.

If anyone knows what is the problem or what is extra in android 4.4 to cause the custom styleable to not launch please help.

Here is the code i use and it works perfect on android 2.2 up to 4.3 (tested with phones and simulators).

Layout :

```
     <com.example.mobile.view.CustomCell
                xmlns:cc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mobile"
                android:id="@+id/B1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/customcell_height"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                cc:editable="false"
                cc:labelText="@string/GrossIncome" />
```

Class:

```
package com.example.mobile.view;
public class CustomCell extends RelativeLayout implements TextWatcher {

private Context mContext;
private AttributeSet mAttributeSet;

private TextView mTextViewLabel;
private EditText mEditTextValue;

private boolean mEditable = false;

private CellUpdateListener mCellUpdateListener;

public CustomCell(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);

    mContext = context;
    mAttributeSet = attributeSet;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.customcell, this);

    mTextViewLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customcell_label);
    mEditTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customcell_value);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Calibri.ttf");
    mTextViewLabel.setTypeface(tf);
    mEditTextValue.setTypeface(tf);
    parseAttributes();
}

private void parseAttributes() {
    String text = null;
    TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(mAttributeSet,
                    R.styleable.com_example_mobile_view_CustomCell);
    CharSequence s = a
                    .getString(R.styleable.com_example_mobile_view_CustomCell_labelText);
    if (s != null) {
        text = s.toString();
        setLabelText(text);
    }

    s = a.getString(R.styleable.com_example_mobile_view_CustomCell_valueText);
    if (s != null) {
        text = s.toString();
        setTextValue(text);
    }

    boolean b = a.getBoolean(
                    R.styleable.com_example_mobile_view_CustomCell_editable,
                    true);
    setEditable(b);

    b = a.getBoolean(
                    R.styleable.com_example_mobile_view_CustomCell_highlight,
                    false);
    if (b) {
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.input_highlighted);

        findViewById(R.id.customcell).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        findViewById(R.id.customcell).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    mEditTextValue.setInputType(a
                    .getInt(R.styleable.com_example_mobile_view_CustomCell_android_inputType,
                                    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT));

    a.recycle();
}

public void setCellUpdateListener(CellUpdateListener cellUpdateListener) {
    mCellUpdateListener = cellUpdateListener;

}

public void setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener l) {
    mEditTextValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(l);
    mEditTextValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
}

private void notifyCellUpdateListener() {
    if (mCellUpdateListener != null) {
        mCellUpdateListener.onCellUpdate(this);
    }
}

public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
    mEditable = editable;
    mEditTextValue.setEnabled(editable);
    mEditTextValue.setFocusableInTouchMode(editable);
    mEditTextValue.setFocusable(editable);
    if (mEditable) {
        mEditTextValue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
    } else {
        mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}

public String getLabelText() {
    return (String) mTextViewLabel.getText();
}

public void setLabelText(String label) {
    this.mTextViewLabel.setText(label);
}

public String getTextValue() {
    return mEditTextValue.getEditableText().toString();
}

public void setTextValue(String value) {
    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    mEditTextValue.setText(value);
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

public int getIntValue() {
    int value = 0;
    String string = mEditTextValue.getEditableText().toString();
    String cleanString = cleanString(string);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cleanString)
                    && !(cleanString.length() == 1 && !TextUtils
                                    .isDigitsOnly(cleanString))) {
        value = Integer.valueOf(cleanString);
    }

    return value;
}

public void setIntValue(int value) {
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setNegativePrefix("(");
    nf.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

    String formated = nf.format(value);

    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    this.mEditTextValue.setText(formated);
    mEditTextValue.setSelection(formated.length());
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

public void setIntValueWithPercentage(int value) {
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setNegativePrefix("(");
    nf.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

    String formated = nf.format(value);
    formated += " %";

    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    this.mEditTextValue.setText(formated);

    String symbol = "%";

    int symbolIndex = formated.indexOf(symbol);
    if (symbolIndex == 0 || symbolIndex < 0) {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(formated.length());
    } else {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(symbolIndex - 1);
    }
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

public void setIntValueWithCurrency(int value) {
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    nf.setNegativePrefix("(");
    nf.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

    String formated = nf.format(value);

    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    this.mEditTextValue.setText(formated);

    String symbol = nf.getCurrency().getSymbol();

    int symbolIndex = formated.indexOf(symbol);
    if (symbolIndex == 0 || symbolIndex < 0) {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(formated.length());
    } else {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(symbolIndex - 1);
    }
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

int getNumberOfDecimalPlace(String value) {
    String string = stripSymbols(value);
    DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

    final int index = string.lastIndexOf(symbols.getDecimalSeparator());
    if (index < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return string.length() - 1 - index;
}

public float getFloatValue() {
    float value = 0;
    String string = mEditTextValue.getEditableText().toString();
    String cleanString = cleanString(string);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cleanString)
                    && !(cleanString.length() == 1 && !TextUtils
                                    .isDigitsOnly(cleanString))) {
        value = Float.valueOf(cleanString);

        // int exp = getNumberOfDecimalPlace(string);

        value /= Math.pow(10, 2);
    }

    return value;
}

public void setFloatValue(float value) {
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setNegativePrefix("(");
    nf.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    String formated = nf.format(value);

    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    this.mEditTextValue.setText(formated);
    mEditTextValue.setSelection(formated.length());
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

public void setFloatValueWithPercentage(float value) {
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setNegativePrefix("(");
    nf.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    String formated = nf.format(value);
    formated += " %";

    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    this.mEditTextValue.setText(formated);

    String symbol = "%";

    int symbolIndex = formated.indexOf(symbol);
    if (symbolIndex == 0 || symbolIndex < 0) {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(formated.length());
    } else {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(symbolIndex - 1);
    }
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

public void setFloatValueWithCurrency(float value) {
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    nf.setNegativePrefix("(");
    nf.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    String formated = nf.format(value);

    mEditTextValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    this.mEditTextValue.setText(formated);

    String symbol = nf.getCurrency().getSymbol();

    int symbolIndex = formated.indexOf(symbol);
    if (symbolIndex == 0 || symbolIndex < 0) {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(formated.length());
    } else {
        mEditTextValue.setSelection(symbolIndex - 1);
    }
    mEditTextValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

String stripSymbols(String string) {
    if (string == null)
        return "";

    String replaceable = "["
                    + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency()
                                    .getSymbol() + "%\\(\\)\\s]";

    String cleanString = string.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

    return cleanString;
}

String cleanString(String string) {
    if (string == null)
        return "";

    String replaceable = "["
                    + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency()
                                    .getSymbol() + "%,.\\s]";

    String cleanString = string.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

    if (cleanString.contains("(")) {
        cleanString.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");
        cleanString = "-" + cleanString;
    }

    return cleanString;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    notifyCellUpdateListener();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

}
```